# Can I write a automatic user message into FB Share window?

Tags: facebook, share

Im using this method:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<url to share>&t=<title of content>
```

Is there any way without an app to show up the dialog with a default message inside the textarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to go with no. There is no documentation mentioning anything about it.

Also the sharer.php method has been depreciated for some time. I suggest you use the facebook like button or a dialog - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

While sharer.php works, Facebook no longer support it. Meaning if it breaks, they won't fix it.